# Merging two datums to create single elevation dataset in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have an SRTM loaded. I also have a landcover data layer.
I want to merge the two datums to create a single elevation data set.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please re-write your question, because it makes no sense

Comment: What @FelixIP said and the answer might be better if we knew at least an outline of what the intended final use is for your "single elevation data set".

Answer (score 2):

To simply merge or append, see this question on [Combining Layers Using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4673/combining-layers-using-arcmap).Be advised, that you will need to ensure that your two datasets are using the same data types for columns that you are wishing to merge, that your column lengths are similar so you don't truncate data, etc.  Basically, make sure your data schema matches. Otherwise, you will end up with data that couldn't be merged, truncated or missing data, etc.

Not knowing the schemas between your two datasets, it is hard to know exactly what clean-up will need to be done, but this should at least get you started.